# How to create Angular FORM in repect of a JSON which is dynamic in nature?

Tags: angular, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

Suppose Today i have a JSON having 2 fields -

> 1.name
>
> 2.age

After a month, a new field got added to that JSON, suppose `DOB`.
After 2 month one more field got added - `address` which is of type **object** itself.

JSON now

1.name

2.age

3.DOB

4.address -

```
          4.1. PO
          4.2. City
          4.3. State
```

The scenario here is , JSON is changing everyday , and in future also it can change. Now having a handcrafted UI (i.e adding new input fields each time) is a pain.

Please tell me some approach or provide a solution for this where my UI will change based on the given JSON .

Comment: Loop through the response and create a new FormControl based on the new key ? Did u try this?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the [forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms) section in the official Angular docs makes a good and interesting read. As you have to maintain big and somewhat complex forms, I would definitly look into [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). They differ from template-driven forms as they're model-driven. Any change made to the data model will reflect in the form using the power of oberservables (streams).

When we dive deeper into the matter, we find that there is a third concept called [dynamic forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form):

> Building handcrafted forms can be costly and time-consuming, especially if you need a great number of them, they're similar to each other, and they change frequently to meet rapidly changing business and regulatory requirements.

Dynamic forms within Angular are basically reactive (model-driven) forms that are created dynamically. The key is the dynamic data binding of metadata used to render the form without making any hardcoded assumptions about specific fields. This concept is quite hard to master, but definitely worth it in the long run. My advice would be to start with the Angular tutorial, so you at least know *how* and *why* it works.

Coming back to your question; there are libraries out there that did most of the hard work for you. You might want to take a look at [Formly](https://github.com/formly-js/ngx-formly). Formly allows you to create JSON powered forms by using the power of dynamic forms. Creating a form field is dead simple:

```
{
    key: 'email',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
        type: 'email',
        label: 'Email address',
        placeholder: 'Enter email',
        required: true,
    }
}
```

To take things even further, I have built a [form builder](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-form-builder?file=app%2Fform-builder%2FREADME.md) that can be used to produce formly-compatible JSON formats by chaining methods. It allows for clean code and typehinting, making it impossible to create faulty formly field configurations. We can create the same field as above using the form builder:

```
builder
  .input('email', 'text')
  .label('Email address')
  .placeholder('Enter email')
  .required();
```

You can play with the [form builder on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-form-builder).

Good luck!

Comment: Could you please take a dynamic JSON and share a code snippet